# How to handle empty values during a data replacement from a table to another in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an e-commerce shop and once a week the warehouse puts in another table only products that have changed their price. How to update the prices in the first table with the new prices of the selected products in the other table? Feel free to use also some php if it's not possible to do with mysql only.

I tried this command but when the SELECT founds no matches it changes my original prices to 0 instead of leaving them untouched.

```
UPDATE product_catalogue pc
SET pc.price = (SELECT new_price
                FROM product_catalogue_updated pcu
                WHERE pc.product_id = pcu.product_id)
```

Comment: use a `where` in the `update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
UPDATE product_catalogue pc
SET pc.price = (
  SELECT new_price
  FROM product_catalogue_updated pcu
  WHERE pc.product_id = pcu.product_id
)
WHERE pc.product_id IN (
  SELECT pcu.product_id FROM product_catalogue_updated pcu
)
```

<strike>This might work as well:</strike>

This doesn't work (but would be nice):

```
UPDATE product_catalogue pc
SET pc.price = (
  SELECT new_price
  FROM product_catalogue_updated pcu
  WHERE pc.product_id = pcu.product_id
) AS pprice
WHERE pprice IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The first solution works perfectly.
The second one gives me this error:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS pprice WHERE pprice IS NOT NULL' at line 6" but it's not important because my problem is solved with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE product_catalogue pc,product_catalogue_updated pcu 
SET pc.price = pcu.new_price 
WHERE pc.product_id = pcu.product_id
```

BACKUP YOUR DB BEFORE USING THIS QUERY

Comment: You don't seem very confident with your own answer :-)

Comment: No. I confident in my answer. It saves author from mistakes if he had forgotten something when asked the question

Comment: Note that I still prefer explicit `JOIN`s over the comma operator :-)

Comment: Thanks guys both of you for the help.

Comment: @Mikhail Easier to notice there is a join going on; priority is strictly left-to-right (commas take precedence over JOINs); you can use USING. Join conditions should not go to the WHERE section.